SQL error when empty tags array in Spring Data JPA
I have this method
@Query(value = "SELECT s.id, s.title, s.teacher_id, s.short_description, s.time_exam_end, s.time_start FROM subjects s " +
            "JOIN tags_subject t ON s.id = t.subject_id " +
            "WHERE (s.time_exam_end > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() * 1000) " +
            "AND (:tags IS NULL OR t.tag IN :tags) " +
            "AND ((:has_exam IS NULL) OR (:has_exam = true AND s.exam <> '') OR (:has_exam = false AND s.exam = '')) " +
            "GROUP BY t.tag, s.id, s.title, s.teacher_id, s.short_description, s.time_exam_end, s.time_start " +
            "HAVING :tag_count = 0 OR COUNT(t.tag) = :tag_count " +
            "limit 10 offset :pos ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<SubjectAnnounceDB> findAccessAnnounceSubject(int pos, String[] tags, Boolean has_exam, int tag_count);

    default List<SubjectAnnounceDB> findAccessAnnounceSubject(int pos, String[] tags, Boolean has_exam) {
        return findAccessAnnounceSubject(pos, tags, has_exam, tags == null ? 0 : tags.length);
    }

and when all the parameters are in place, then everything works fine (tags and has_exam are allowed null), but when tags = null it gives an error
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'null) AND ((1 IS NULL) OR (1 = true AND s.exam <> '') OR (1 = false AND s.exam =' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:121)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:972)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:246)
    ... 101 more

I tried add condition LENGTH(:tags) = 0, but unsuccessfully

Was my answer helpful? It seems to have got into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78577539. If so please could I have an acceptance?

Put some parentheses round your :tags in your IN clause:
 "AND (:tags IS NULL OR t.tag IN (:tags)) "

I have tried this on HSQLDB (so not quite the same) and it is fine for the tags being null, non-empty and empty. Without the parentheses it fails for null, like yours does.
