SQL Query Subquery Not Filtering Correctly with Spring Boot
i have this repository for search not announced_subject
package com.tetradunity.server.repositories;
import com.tetradunity.server.entities.SubjectEntity;
import com.tetradunity.server.models.SubjectFilter;
import com.tetradunity.server.projections.AnnounceSubjectProjection;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public interface SubjectRepository extends CrudRepository<SubjectEntity, Long> {
    Optional<SubjectEntity> findById(long id);

    @Query(value = "SELECT s.id, s.title, s.teacher_id, s.short_description, s.time_exam_end, s.time_start " +
            "FROM subjects s " +
            "JOIN ( " +
            "    SELECT subject_id " +
            "    FROM tags_subject " +
            "    WHERE (:tags IS NULL OR LENGTH(:tags) = 0 OR tag IN (:tags)) " +
            "    GROUP BY subject_id " +
            "    HAVING (:tags IS NULL OR LENGTH(:tags) = 0 OR COUNT(DISTINCT tag) >= LENGTH(:tags)) " +
            ") t ON s.id = t.subject_id " +
            "JOIN users u ON u.id = s.teacher_id " +
            "WHERE (s.time_exam_end > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() * 1000) " +
            "AND ((:has_exam IS NULL) OR (:has_exam = true AND s.exam <> '') OR (:has_exam = false AND s.exam = '')) " +
            "AND (:email_teacher IS NULL OR u.email LIKE :email_teacher%) " +
            "LIMIT 10 OFFSET :pos", nativeQuery = true)
    List<AnnounceSubjectProjection> findAccessAnnounceSubject(int pos, String[] tags, Boolean has_exam, String email_teacher);

    default List<AnnounceSubjectProjection> findAccessAnnounceSubject(int pos, SubjectFilter filter) {
        if (filter == null) {
            return findAccessAnnounceSubject(pos, null, null, null);
        }

        String[] tags = filter.getTags();
        return findAccessAnnounceSubject(pos, tags == null ? new String[0] : tags, filter.getHas_exam(), filter.getEmail_teacher());
    }
}

and if remove all mentions of tags, it work correctly, but with tags doesn't output anything
i tried add :tags IS NULL but to no avail

Explanation of the problem
The sql LENGTH function takes Strings as its parameter, and therefore will cause an error if you have more than one tag. If you have one tag, but the length of the tag is more than one character, then this condition will not hold: COUNT(DISTINCT tag) >= LENGTH(:tags))
Solution
I suggest you put your tag-length in as a separate parameter rather than calculating it in SQL:
import com.tetradunity.server.entities.SubjectEntity;
import com.tetradunity.server.models.SubjectFilter;
import com.tetradunity.server.projections.AnnounceSubjectProjection;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public interface SubjectRepository extends CrudRepository<SubjectEntity, Long> {
    Optional<SubjectEntity> findById(long id);

    @Query(value = "SELECT s.id, s.title, s.teacher_id, s.short_description, s.time_exam_end, s.time_start " +
            "FROM subjects s " +
            "JOIN ( " +
            "    SELECT subject_id " +
            "    FROM tags_subject " +
            "    WHERE (:tag_number = 0 OR tag IN (:tags)) " +
            "    GROUP BY subject_id " +
            "    HAVING (:tag_number = 0 OR COUNT(DISTINCT tag) >= :tag_number) " +
            ") t ON s.id = t.subject_id " +
            "JOIN users u ON u.id = s.teacher_id " +
            "WHERE (s.time_exam_end > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() * 1000) " +
            "AND ((:has_exam IS NULL) OR (:has_exam = true AND s.exam <> '') OR (:has_exam = false AND s.exam = '')) " +
            "AND (:email_teacher IS NULL OR u.email LIKE :email_teacher%) " +
            "LIMIT 10 OFFSET :pos", nativeQuery = true)
    List<AnnounceSubjectProjection> findAccessAnnounceSubject(int pos, String[] tags, Boolean has_exam, String email_teacher, int tag_number);

    default List<AnnounceSubjectProjection> findAccessAnnounceSubject(int pos, SubjectFilter filter) {
        if (filter == null) {
            return findAccessAnnounceSubject(pos, null, null, null, 0);
        }

        String[] tags = filter.getTags() == null? new String[0]: filter.getTags();
        return findAccessAnnounceSubject(pos, tags, filter.getHas_exam(), filter.getEmail_teacher(), tags.length);
    }
}

